# tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath: crash when popping viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a viewController with a `UITableView`, the rows of which I allow to edit (delete) with a swipe - much like in the Mail app. I do it with, among other, this method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YES;
}
```

However, if I have a delete button revealed, and at the same time I use back navigation of my `UINavigationController`, i.e. when I `popViewControllerAnimated:`, the app crashes with the following message:

**[ViewController tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xaae64d0**

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: In your view controller's `dealloc` method, set the table view's `editing` property to `NO`.

Comment: And set it's `delegate` and `dataSource` properties to `nil`. Although it's strange that you'd have to do this...

Comment: Excellent! Your first comment is right on the spot, the other two calls are not necessary. I'll be happy to accept your answer if you create one.

Comment: This bug is still live'n'kicking in March 2015 (iOS 8.2, with XCode 6.2).  Excellent advice given here in the comments, I simply added the "tableView.editing = false" in my UIViewController's "viewWillDisappear" function.  This was enough to stop the app crashing completely !!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In your view controller's `dealloc` method, set the table view's `editing` property to `NO`.

Comment: This works but it only started happening in iOS7. Any idea why?

Comment: Hope we are all submitted Bug Reports :)

Comment: At first, I thought this is a random crash because of system bugs because crashlytics tells me only few people(out of thousands) having this issue. Now I know why and get my app fixed!

Comment: Nice find. I see Apple still hasn't fixed this.

Answer (score 42):

I had the same problem, but I was using ARC and I didn't want to be mucking about in the dealloc method. Doing it in viewWillDisappear was sufficient to stop the crash.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [table setEditing:NO];
}
```

Comment: Is it wrong to have a dealloc method under ARC as long as you don't call [super dealloc]?

Comment: It's not wrong. The accepted answer won't break anything and will compile normally. You literally won't be allowed to call `[super dealloc]` or `release` as ARC is supposed to call them for you. My suggestion was mostly to reduce confusion since I didn't want an unusual dealloc method when none of my other classes have one. It also feels weird to be setting a property on an object moments before it will likely be released.

Comment: This method will sometimes cause weird behaviour if you present other vcs etc so I would use the dealloc method.

Comment: `viewDidDisappear:` also works, which I prefer in this case as the user doesn't see the tableview transitioning out of the editing state.

Comment: I know it's a small detail but it's better to call [table setEditing:animated] and let system decide whether it's animated transition or not.

Comment: Decided to go with this method as it makes more sense in an ARC project. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use

   tableview.delegate = nil in dealloc()
2. Use

   tableView=nil

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I recently had this problem, and thought others might benefit from what I found: I am using Xcode 9 and iOS 11, and I am employing the new method of using a SearchController.  If I clicked the system back button while I was searching, I got the fatal on tableView(_: canEditRowAt indexPath:).  Changing setEditing to false did not solve my issue.  The problem was that I returned true/false in my canEditRowAt override depending upon if my data source had records, but when I was searching, I had a different data source (a filtering array).  Once I checked against the right data source, the back button worked.